# pseudo elements size too small on large and extra large screens

Tags: css

I am showing a caret symbol on chat messages in my UI. They appear to be fine in small and medium devices but too tiny on large and extra large devices. Can any one please let me know how to handle it. I tried to display:inline-block and set height/width but doesnt seem to accurate. Can any one please tell me the correct direction

https://jsfiddle.net/7ba2od0L/

Medium screens -

[image]

Large screens -

[image]

CSS -

```
.bot-msg::before{
  top: 1px;
    bottom: -3px;
    left: -20px;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-bottom-color: #009fa8;
    border-width: 10px;
    right: -8px;
    transform: rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
    -moz-transform: rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
    -ms-transform: rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
    -o-transform: rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
    -webkit-transform: rotate( 270deg ) skew( 0deg );
    top: 6px;
}
```

HTML -

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="chatbox">
        <div id="speedtest">
         
        </div>     
        <div class="chatbox-wrapper">
          <div class="header">
            <div class="barsection">
              <ul >
                <li class="clrbg"></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="mediasection">
              
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="chat-history">
            <ul class="main">
              <!-- <span class="bot-msg-data-time">27 Feb, 06:17 PM</span> -->
              <li class="bot-msg">              
                <div class="msgtext">Thanks, Scott for your interest in applying to HGS. I'm Sophie, your virtual assistant. Let's get started. I got your mobile number as 636-762-9733 & would like to verify it.
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="bot-msg">
                <div class="msgtext">
                  Can I send you a one-time code over text (text charges may apply)?
  
                  <span class="tip">You can skip this if you like, just type </span>
                </div>
                
              </li>
```

Here is a fiddle for your reference - https://jsfiddle.net/7ba2od0L/

Comment: @RubixOverflow Added the HTML code please take a look

Comment: @RubixOverflow Here is a fiddle for your reference - https://jsfiddle.net/7ba2od0L/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not a real issue at all. It looked differently on emulator but was working perfectly on actual device.